# Are there any specifications of the inside of Star Wars ships available?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

I have been wondering if the specifications of the inside of any Star Wars ship have been revealed before? I am trying to find a website that shows the whole inside of a Star Wars ship and maybe lists some general characteristics of it.

I'm ideally looking for some designs for Capital ships as well as and customized or rare ships such as Mon Calamari Cruisers, Super Star Destroyer, Star Destroyers, The Millennium Falcon, etc., rather than the fighters (unless they were customized or rare ships).

The big requirement I was looking for is the ability walk through them in 3D(!) and see the different sections of the ships. Although, if it is a magazine technical-print that would help too.

Comment: For walking through a ship in 3d, various Star Wars video games (Knight of the Old Republic 1 and 2, Shadows of the Empire, etc) have you walking through some sort of ship.

Comment: “I have been wondering if the specifications of the inside of any Star Wars ship have been revealed before?” — I think you mean “created”, rather than revealed. Specifications for fictional ships don’t exist unless someone made them up, and it would probably be a bit redundant to bother making them up unless you were going to show them to the audience.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, sometimes the best stories are those where the author plans something with a lot of detail but only lets us viewers/readers glimpse part of it - all does fit together, the story feels more natural than if they had not thought about it in much detail at all.

Comment: @Ned64: sure! Star Wars is not that kind of story.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite lol  You are right, sadly :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're after a "look inside" the various craft seen on screen in the Star Wars universe, you'll be wanting to get hold of copies of...

- **[Star Wars: The Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Vehicles_and_Vessels)**
- [Star Wars: Blueprints](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1611097967)
- **[Star Wars Complete Cross-Sections: The Spacecraft and Vehicles of the Entire Star Wars Saga](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756627044)**
- [**Star Wars: The Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections)
- [Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection)
- [Star Wars Blueprints: Rebel Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_Rebel_Edition)
- [Star Wars : Episode 1 Insider's Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_Insider%27s_Guide)
- [Haynes Millennium Falcon Owner's Workshop Manual](http://www.haynes.co.uk/millenniumfalcon/)
- [Haynes Death Star Owner's Technical Manual](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_Owner%27s_Technical_Manual)

There is also a wide range of scanned drawings online [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Technical_drawing_images).
[image]

[image]

Comment: Good answer, except that instead of buying "Star Wars: Incredible Cross Sections" and "Revenge of the Sith: Incredible Cross Sections" separately, it's cheaper to just get "Star Wars: Complete Cross Sections" which includes everything from both (along with Phantom Menace and Attack of the Clones cross sections), at http://www.amazon.com/Star-Wars-Complete-Cross-Sections-Spacecraft/dp/0756627044 ...might also check out "Star Wars: The Blueprints" (though I think it's not 'in-universe' but more like production blueprints) at http://www.amazon.com/Star-Wars-Blueprints-J-Rinzler/dp/1611097967

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Cheerfully added.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late response. I would have to say a good amount of those drawings are detailed. Good post. I gave you +1 for that too.

Comment: +1 for the Essential Guide. Oh man. That book was a gem.

Comment: Excuse me but the star wars incredible cross section as like the UE is not canon . I mean i have observed the firepower of the turbolaser and i calculate the speed of the A-Wing and the kinetic force who can penetrate the Star Destroyer and i find which the major party of the firepower of the star wars Univers is to medium kilotons at the low megatons explosive . Of Course the death star are the only ship who exceed this limit. I love Star Wars but i think i won't tolerate the fanatic of the scifi Universe who don't care the universe of the author who create this (sorry i am french and i am no